# How does it benefit security if a table owner is a nologin role in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, security, roles

Apart from every other security measure, how does it benefit security if a table owner is a nologin role in Postgres?

Suppose my master role that can login is admin123 (Amazon RDS).

For example. I could do A:

```
CREATE ROLE nologinrole;
GRANT nologinrole TO admin123;

CREATE SCHEMA data;
ALTER SCHEMA data OWNER TO nologinrole;

CREATE TABLE data.test(...);
ALTER TABLE data.test OWNER TO nologinrole;
```

Or simply B.

```
CREATE SCHEMA data;

CREATE TABLE data.test(...);

-- All owned by admin123
```

Is A safer because the schema and table are owned by a role that cannot login? Why? I suppose not since the admin123 role that is able to log in, is granted to the nologin role. And if that's the case I could just as well do B. But I'm curious to learn why A is better.

Comment: yes - if you grant owner to login role - it has no benefits obviously. but if you have owner, that can't login. and grant actions on its objects - there is. the user that can do anything just cant login (putting aside su of course)

Comment: Thanks, @VaoTsun. I changed the question a bit to ask for the reasons why to hopefully trigger people to elaborate. Also I narrowed it down to tables instead of objects.

Comment: the day the DBA leaves (or whoever had access to that login), you don't need to change every schema owner account/pws, you just revoke the granted roles and you assign them to the new DBA.